# Error- Elasticsearch-full getting an error explained the the question

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, magento2.4

I install elasticsearch-full on Mac(chip - Apple M1 Pro ).BY Running this commands.

```
brew tap elastic/tap
brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

Installed successfully and when after started the elastic search.
I run the command `brew services list`

I am getting below error

> Name               Status     User     File
>
> elasticsearch-full error  256 root     ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch-full.plist

I want to install magento 2 on nginx server on Mac.

If anyone came across the same issue can you please guide me to fix this.